# How to use linfa_preprocessing::CountVectorizer to replicate python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, rust, vectorization

I'm using Rust to implement some Python code for text processing. For my task, I want to re-write this Python code:

```py
count_vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=2)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(train_df['data'])
count_vect._validate_vocabulary()
```

I tried this:

```rust
use linfa_preprocessing;
use linfa_preprocessing::{CountVectorizer};

fn main() {
    let _df = CsvReader::from_path().unwrap().finish().unwrap()
    let count_vect = CountVectorizer();

}
```